# Unable to run stored procedure in OUTER APPLY

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have the following SQL in Linqpad:

```
WITH dp AS
(
    SELECT v.DataPartitionId
    FROM Surge.VirtualHost as v
    WHERE v.DataPartitionId != 1 AND v.DataPartitionId != 11
)
SELECT * FROM dp OUTER APPLY DeleteSite(dp.DataPartitionId);
```

I'm attempting to run a stored procedure against multiple rows in a table. Linqpad is giving me the following error:

```
Error 208: Invalid Object name 'DeleteSite'.
```

I'm able to run the stored procedure manually by putting in a value. I've checked that it exists and I've rerun the alter procedure, but I'm still running into the same issue. The stored procedure is showing in the tree view, in the correct database. (I've tried specifying the schema as well, to no avail.)

From what I understand, `OUTER APPLY` should run the procedure for each row - meaning that the value should be passed in (in this case, an int). Is my understanding flawed? Has anyone run into something like this before?

Comment: Is `DeleteSite` a stored procedure or a function?  You can use APPLY with functions but not stored procedures.

Comment: @bluefeet It's a stored procedure. I didn't realize you couldn't use APPLY with stored procedures?

Comment: You can't use it with a stored procedure, you might be able to rewrite the procedure as a function and then you can use APPLY with it.

Comment: @bluefeet If you write that as an answer, I'll accept it. I learned something new today!

Comment: No need to post an answer, this was a duplicate - see the question that this is a duplicate of. :)